# How to convert a propositional formula to conjunctive normal form (CNF)?

Tags: math, boolean-logic

How can I convert this equation to CNF?

```
¬((p ∨ ¬Q) ⊃ R) ⊃ (P ∧ R))
```

Comment: Some of those symbols are nonstandard. What's ⊃ supposed to be in Boolean logic?

Comment: i was gona ask the same question

Comment: I'm guessing it is the '->' symbol

Comment: yes , i just read about you are right jordan

Answer (score 29):

To convert a [propositional formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositional_calculus) to [conjunctive normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form), perform the following two steps:

1. Push negations into the formula, repeatedly applying [De Morgan's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws), until all negations only apply to atoms. You obtain a formula in [negation normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negation_normal_form).

   - `¬(p ∨ q)` to `(¬p) ∧ (¬q)`
   - `¬(p ∧ q)` to `(¬p) ∨ (¬q)`
2. Repeatedly apply the [distributive law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property) where a disjunction occurs over a conjunction. Once this is not possible anymore, the formula is in CNF.

   - `p ∨ (q ∧ r)` to `(p ∨ q) ∧ (p ∨ r)`

To obtain a formula in disjunctive normal form, simply apply the distribution of `∧` over `∨` in step 2.

#### Note about `⊂`

The subset symbol (`⊂`) used in the question is just an alternative notation for the logical implication/entailment, which is usually written as an arrow (`⇒`).