# SAT normal conjunctiva form

Tags: sat

Do you think that it is possible to compile a propositional formula towards a SAT problem of similar size whose solution allows us to find a valuation which satisfies the starting formula? If so, explain the method you would use.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert a propositional formula to conjunctive normal form (CNF)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/655261/how-to-convert-a-propositional-formula-to-conjunctive-normal-form-cnf)

Answer (score 0):

This questions seems to be already answered here:
[How to convert a propositional formula to conjunctive normal form (CNF)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/655261/how-to-convert-a-propositional-formula-to-conjunctive-normal-form-cnf)
SAT-solvers usually take a CNF in dimcas format as input.